# Duplicating error message in Tabular Form APEX 5

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a tabular form in APEX 5 with a PLSQL Function (Return Error Text) validation type.

When i add the following 3 rows:

```
Row 1 : A & 2

Row 2 : A & 3

Row 3 : A & 1 -> This values already exists in the database and should return an error.
```

I'm getting this:

> "A & 1 already exists in database. (Row 1)"
>
> "A & 1 already exists in database. (Row 2)"
>
> "A & 1 already exists in database. (Row 3)"

I want to get this:

> "A & 1 already exists in database. (Row 3)"

I'm getting more then one error which is not correct, i should get just one for row 3. I think this is because of the Execution scope properties of the validation. The only 2 options that I have are:

- For created and modified rows (using this)
- All submitted rows

I call the validation function with an array and looping through it then returning a varchar text for the validation.

Here is my [validation code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbJBf.png):

Comment: can you post your validation code?

Comment: Hi Brenners, already posted. Can you help me.? Thanks

Comment: If you want the user to see notification about your answer in comments, put`@` before the user's name.

Comment: Ahh Thank you @Dmitry..

Comment: Hi @brenners1302 already posted. Can you help me.? Thanks

Comment: Solved..:) I am store my tabular form to collection first, and then validated it. Thanks All @Dmitry

Comment: Solved Thanks @brenners1302

Comment: @user5746007 you should post your answer and how you solved the problem for anyone else having a similar conundrum